# Would the environmental pressures imposed by humans make the housefly of today significantly harder to swat than their ancestors of 1000 years ago?

Tags: evolution, entomology, natural-selection

For context, I am primarily referring to *Musca domestica*.

Recently the thought occurred to me that due to short life cycle of the common housefly, and due to the fact that such flies have interacted with humans for thousands of years, it would be rather likely that human beings have served as an environmental factor that have affected the evolution of houseflies. Because of the short life cycle of the common housefly, would they been able to rabidly adjust to the environmental pressure of humans swatting them? Would the housefly of today be noticeably harder to swat than the flies of a thousand years ago? Would their be any way to know for sure?

Comment: I'm wondering how much of a dent in the fly population swatting makes. Perhaps you might show your research into the relative swat/survival rate (we're meant to show our prior attempts to answer when asking anyhow). Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for our guidelines.

Comment: @JiminyCricket Hi! Thank you for your response. I do not understand what you mean by providing my research. Do you mean research done by myself on the topic, research that might help with finding an answer, or my own research?

Comment: Suggestions; perhaps what you can find online about population density in your selected area (urban?), mean survival numbers to adult fly stage per generation, anything about mutation rates (?), and the likely numbers that you'd need to swat in order to make a dent in the population constituting selective pressure. Whatever you can't find/deduce, perhaps we can fill in some of the details, remembering that no population is going to be completely isolated, because - flies.

Comment: Cows have been around for ten thousands years,. Wildebeests for millions. Both have built-in fly swatters. They don’t seem to be swatting furiously. How could we possibly know? It’s not like records have been kept on attempts/successful-hits ratios. The answer is, “Maybe, who knows?” I’m sure there’s plenty of research on domestic flies and their abilities. This site requires that you show some effort to answer your question.

Comment: @JiminyCricket. Hello, thank you for your quick reply.

I have some studies that might be relevant to answering this question:

I found that study that shows that Musca domestica adapts very quickly to existential evolutionary pressures: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/ps.5409

I also found this article that shows the average flight range of Musca domestica: https://eprints.um.edu.my/5793/

Finally, this article explains the mutation rate of Musca: https://portlandpress.com/biochemj/article-abstract/359/1/175/38665/Identification-and-characterization-of-mutations

Comment: Ah, that's great, can you now [edit] the question with any relevant info you found (plus the links). I'll make a point of checking back later, see if i can help at all.